# How to merge route parameters in MenuBuidler for language switcher functionality using KnpMenuBundle and Symfony3

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, symfony, knpmenubundle, knpmenu

### Introduction

In my personal project I am using:

- XAMPP with PHP `v7.1.6`
- Symfony `v3.3.6`
- KnpMnenuBundle `dev-master / 2.2.x-dev` [[link 1]](https://packagist.org/packages/knplabs/knp-menu#dev-master), [[link 2]](https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/KnpMenuBundle/index.html), [[link 3]](https://github.com/KnpLabs/KnpMenuBundle) in order to manage Menus.
- Bootstrap `v3.3.7`
- Bootstrap and KnpMenuBundle integration [[link 4]](https://gist.github.com/Invis1ble/503db8bb9ff6dafc52c8b2bf7c6fec42)

### Setting up

To setup i used documentation in [2], [3] and code samples [4]. My menu is working, integration between `Bootstrap` and `KnpMenuBundle` also works.

### Problem

In order to implement `language switcher`, i am using `twig` templates.

It works fine, but i would like to move to more scalable approach - namely - using dedicated bundle (KnpMenuBundle).

At the moment `MenuBuilder` produces ugly URLs (shown in results section of `code sample 1`). I would like it to generate links that are shown in results section of `code sample 2`.

I do not know how to achieve that.

### Question

How can one produce pretty URLs using MenuBuilder?

How can one force merging of route parameters in `MenuBuilder`?

### CODE: sample 1

sample of my `MenuBuilder`

```
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language LV', array('label' => 'language.lv', 'route' => 'homepage_lv', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'lv')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language EN', array('label' => 'language.en', 'route' => 'homepage_en', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'en')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language RU', array('label' => 'language.ru', 'route' => 'homepage_ru', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'ru')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
```

produces following links:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/lv/?_locale=lv
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/?_locale=en
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/?_locale=ru

locale change does not occurs

### CODE: sample 2

conventional `Menu` twig template

```
<li><a href="{{ path(current_route, app.request.get('_route_params') | merge({'_locale': 'lv'})) }}">{{ "language.lv" | trans({}, "language") }}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path(current_route, app.request.get('_route_params') | merge({'_locale': 'en'})) }}">{{ "language.en" | trans({}, "language") }}</a></li>
<li><a href="{{ path(current_route, app.request.get('_route_params') | merge({'_locale': 'ru'})) }}">{{ "language.ru" | trans({}, "language") }}</a></li>
```

produces following links:

- http://127.0.0.1:8000/lv/home
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/en/home
- http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/home

actually changes locale after clicking on them

### CODE: sample 3

relevant part of my `routing.yml` file

```
# redirecting home
homepage:
    path: /
    defaults:
        _controller: 'FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect'
        route: home
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_lv:
    path: /lv/
    defaults:
        _controller: 'FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect'
        route: home
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_en:
    path: /en/
    defaults:
        _controller: 'FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect'
        route: home
        permanent: true

# redirecting home
homepage_ru:
    path: /ru/
    defaults:
        _controller: 'FrameworkBundle:Redirect:redirect'
        route: home
        permanent: true

home:
    path:     /{_locale}/home
    defaults: { _controller: 'AppBundle:Home:home' }
    requirements:
        _locale: lv|en|ru
```

### Conclusion

Please advise.

Thank you for your time and knowledge.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it looks like, that `routes` with `parameters` in `MenuBuilder` (as opposed to `routes` in `twig` templates) does not handle `redirects` in `routing.yml`

That means that correct syntax for my case is:

```
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language LV', array('label' => 'language.lv', 'route' => 'home', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'lv')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language EN', array('label' => 'language.en', 'route' => 'home', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'en')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
$language['Language']->setChildrenAttribute("class", "dropdown-menu")
    ->addChild('Language RU', array('label' => 'language.ru', 'route' => 'home', 'routeParameters' => array('_locale' => 'ru')))
    ->setExtra('translation_domain', 'language');
```

And it results in pretty URLs.